# Pandas converting row with unix timestamp (in milliseconds) to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to process a huge amount of CSV files where the time stamp is always a string representing the unix timestamp in milliseconds. I could not find a method yet to modify these columns efficiently.

This is what I came up with, however this of course duplicates only the column and I have to somehow put it back to the original dataset. I'm sure it can be done when creating the `DataFrame`?

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = 'RUN,UNIXTIME,VALUE\n1,1447160702320,10\n2,1447160702364,20\n3,1447160722364,42'

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))

convert = lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x / 1e3)
converted_df = df['UNIXTIME'].apply(convert)
```

This will pick the column 'UNIXTIME' and change it from

```
0    1447160702320
1    1447160702364
2    1447160722364
Name: UNIXTIME, dtype: int64
```

into this

```
0   2015-11-10 14:05:02.320
1   2015-11-10 14:05:02.364
2   2015-11-10 14:05:22.364
Name: UNIXTIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, I would like to use something like `pd.apply()` to get the whole dataset returned with the converted column or as I already wrote, simply create datetimes when generating the DataFrame from CSV.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can do this as a post processing step using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and passing arg `unit='ms'`:

```
In [5]:
df['UNIXTIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UNIXTIME'], unit='ms')
df

Out[5]:
   RUN                UNIXTIME  VALUE
0    1 2015-11-10 13:05:02.320     10
1    2 2015-11-10 13:05:02.364     20
2    3 2015-11-10 13:05:22.364     42
```

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that `unit` parameter, thanks, that's a nice one! I'll make a pull request to include that in `.read_csv` too via parse_dates.

Comment: This may lead to the wrong time because of timezone issue.

Comment: @PengjuZhao the OP's question makes no mention of timezone, for that Teudimundo's answer solves that

Comment: One suggestion is that maybe you can try to add Teudimundo's answer to your answer.  It will be useful for newbie like me.

Comment: @PengjuZhao it's bad practice to cannibalise other users' answers, something I don't do but some others do. I think it's fine for multiple answers so long as they are distinct enough

Answer (score 14):

I use the @EdChum solution, but I add the timezone management:

```
df['UNIXTIME']=pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(pd['UNIXTIME'], unit='ms'))\
                 .tz_localize('UTC' )\
                 .tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

the `tz_localize` indicates that timestamp should be considered as regarding 'UTC', then the `tz_convert` actually moves the date/time to the correct timezone (in this case `America/New_York').

Note that it has been converted to a `DatetimeIndex` because the `tz_` methods works only on the index of the series. Since Pandas 0.15 one can use `.dt`:

```
df['UNIXTIME']=pd.to_datetime(df['UNIXTIME'], unit='ms')\
                 .dt.tz_localize('UTC' )\
                 .dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')
```

Comment: This method works best for yahoo timestamp conversion .The second one not the first one.

Comment: Agree, second does great job of managing timezone - was getting results for start time and end times that were crossing dates and this fix that issue ('America/Chicago'); watch the syntax, was getting unexpected line ending error.

Comment: Every datetime contains a '-05:00' appendix, indicating the difference between timezones in hours. What is the best way to exclude it?

Comment: What you see how panda presents the values, the column internally use the  datetime type. If you want instead to have a string that represent the datetime in the format you prefer you can use `df['UNIXTIME'].dt.strftime(...)` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), note that the result is a Series of string values. If you assign it to the same column: `df['UNIXTIME'] = df['UNIXTIME'].dt.strftime(...)` you won't be able to use the values in the column as datetime anymore because they would be string.

Answer (score 4):

if you know the timestamp unit, use `Series.astype`:

```
df['UNIXTIME'].astype('datetime64[ms]')

0   2015-11-10 13:05:02.320
1   2015-11-10 13:05:02.364
2   2015-11-10 13:05:22.364
Name: UNIXTIME, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

To return the entire DataFrame, use

```
df.astype({'UNIXTIME': 'datetime64[ms]'})

   RUN                UNIXTIME  VALUE
0    1 2015-11-10 13:05:02.320     10
1    2 2015-11-10 13:05:02.364     20
2    3 2015-11-10 13:05:22.364     42
```

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a solution I guess:

```
convert = lambda x: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(x) / 1e3)

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), parse_dates=['UNIXTIME'], date_parser=convert)
```

I'm still not sure if this is the best one though.