# How to convert a column in df having epoch with date time format and vice-versa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, epoch

1.have df with values

```
    0            1 
0 sun       | 1549628346168
1 goal      | 1532230566808
2 micheal   | 1533647352218
```

output should be in the format of

```
    0            1 
0 sun       | 2019-02-02 Sat 21:16:20
1 goal      | 2019-02-02 Sat 21:16:20
2 micheal   | 2019-02-02 Sat 21:16:20
```

tried this how to get day in words

```
s = time/1000
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

2.

have df with values how to concat these two and get a column with epoch time

```
    Date           Time 
0  08-09-2017 |  05:00 PM
1  16-06-17   |  10:27 AM
2   04-07-17  |  03:11 PM
```

output

```
    time
 1549628346168
 1532230566808
 1533647352218
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit='ms'` first and then [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with add `%a` for days, check also http://strftime.org/:

```
df[1] = pd.to_datetime(df[1], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S')

print (df)
         0                        1
0      sun  2019-02-08 Fri 12:19:06
1     goal  2018-07-22 Sun 03:36:06
2  micheal  2018-08-07 Tue 13:09:12
```

EDIT:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']).astype(np.int64) // 10**9
print (df)
         Date      Time          dt
0  08-09-2017  05:00 PM  1502298000
1    16-06-17  10:27 AM  1497608820
2    04-07-17  03:11 PM  1491577860
```

Comment: how to convert these   `2018-07-07 Sat 05:02:00`  into these `2018-07-07  05:02:00`  used this   `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`     got this error  non convertible value 2018-07-07 Sat 05:02:00 with the unit 'ms'

Comment: @hukkemaaru - remove `ms`, it is use for unix format

Comment: @hukkemaaru - It is use for converting datetimes like `1447160702320` - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34883101)

Comment: sure will do that